# state not updating in child component - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing a state from one component to another component. However, when a state updates in the parent component, the child component doesn't update. Is there something i am doing wrong in my code below .

As shown below, in the **Patient.JS** i pass the state to the **AddPatient.JS**. But when i the state of age is updated in the **Patient.JS**, it doesn't update in the **AddPatient.JS**.

How can i handle this ?

**Patient.JS**

```
state = {
    info = {
    age = '',
    name = ''
    }
}
handle_age(event)
   {
      this.setState({ age:event.target.value}, () => {
         console.log('age', this.state.age)


  <Modal>
   <ModalHeader>
   </ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
    <AddPatient
    addNewPatient = {this.state.info}
    />                      
   </ModalBody>
   <ModalFooter>
   <Button  variant="contained" className="text-white" onClick={() => this.addPatient()}>Save</Button>    
    </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
```

**AddPatient**

```
const AddPatient = ({ addNewPatient}) => (
                  <FormGroup>
                       <Label for="className">Age</Label>
                       <Input
                     type="number" 
                     name="sub_total"
                     id="sub_total"
                     placeholder=""
                     value = {addNewPatient.age}
                     />
                   </FormGroup>

       );
```

Comment: Are you setting `age` and passing `info`?

Comment: @acdcjunior, Yes. Since `age` is included in `info`, i am thinking it should be updated once it's state changes in the parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `handle_age` function with this:

```
handle_age(event)
   {
      let info = {...this.state.info}
      info.age = event.target.value
      this.setState({
          info: {...info}
      })
   }
```

**Explanation**: When updating components, React JS does a **shallow** check on the `state` keys and values. What it means, is that it will detect a change when a key/value pair changes or updates, but won't detect a change in deeply nested objects within the `state`. Example:

```
this.state = {
    visible: true,
    users: {
      {
      id: 1,
      name: 'john'
      },
      {
      id: 2,
      name: 'doe'
      }
    }
```

In the above code, React will detect a change in the `visible` key but not in the `users` object because it is a deeply nested object.

Now since you are using only the age of the patient, just pass the age as `patientAge={this.state.info.age}` and use it directly.

Comment: Can you please add some more explanation so i can understand it

Comment: @Switzz sure. i am editing my answer now. but did it work for you though?

Comment: FWIW it may be simpler to just loft `this.state.info` to `this.state` (i.e. remove the nested data) and pass `this.state` to `AddPatient` and leave the handler alone.  This also removes the need to copy the old state value before mutation and allows for normal React state spreading. (i.e. React spreads in new updates)

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the state as a props to the child component so you are now entering the concept of when does change props will trigger a rerender.

if the prop is a primitive value (eg string or integer etc..) it will cause a rerender on every value change.

if the props are an array or like in your example an object, it will cause a rerender only when there's a new reference for that object or array

sense your only changing a property of an object and react dose shallow comparison of state and props, changing "age" will not trigger rerender in child.

you can do:

1. setState to entire info every time which will change his reference and trigger rerender at child

or

2. pass age and name separately as props to your child component

from what I see you are only using age in your child component so I would recommend option 2

like this:

```
<AddPatient
 addNewPatient={this.state.info.age}
/>  



const AddProduct = ({ addNewPatient}) => (
                  <FormGroup>
                       <Label for="className">Age</Label>
                       <Input
                     type="number" 
                     name="sub_total"
                     id="sub_total"
                     placeholder=""
                     value = {addNewPatient}
                     />
                   </FormGroup>

       );
```

Comment: BTW why in your parent component its Called AddPatient and in your child, it's Called AddProduct?

Answer (score 0):

In your handler you are assigning the input value to `state.age` and not inside `state.info.age`

```
handle_age(event) {
  const age = event.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    info: { ...prevState.info, age }
  }), console.log('age', this.state.info.age);
}
```